# I found this white electronic device on my ceiling. What is it?

Tags: ceiling, smoke-detectors

I found this on my ceiling and I was wondering what it is.

[image: A blurry photo of a white device shaped like a rounded square, with a small black outline of the same shape in the center of it. The device has a cluster of 7 holes near one corner.]

Comment: Looks like a smoke alarm.  What you mean you found it on your ceiling?  Not something somebody would break in and put up.  If a smoke alarm they are not life time, need to be replaced every so many years.

Comment: Is this a rental apartment or do you own? If it is a rental, check with your neighbors to see if they have similar items and/or check with management. Could be: smoke alarm, CO alarm (less likely) or some sort of emergency announcement system (though more typically those are on the wall with obvious lights or???

Comment: Use a broom handle to push the large square button in the middle.  Does this cause it to make a very loud noise?  If so, it's probably a smoke detector.  (If not, it's still probably a smoke detector, but the batteries and/or the entire unit need to be replaced.)

Comment: @crip659 If someone had broken in to install it, then it would probably be a microphone and/or camera disguised as a smoke alarm.

Comment: It looks suspect.   Are we sure those holes aren't for microphones and you are probably under heavy surveillance.   I am surprised that you found it.   They should have installed it to match the ceiling color better.   Rookie spies.

Comment: @DMoore I know you are joking, but in all seriousness a smoke detector *would* be a great place to hide a surveillance microphone -- it could probably fit inside the case without interfering with the smoke detection at all, and they're everywhere and nobody looks at them twice.

Comment: @zwol: Disclaimer - this is best done when everyone else is out of the building, unless you like to annoy your housemates/neighbors.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To me, it appears to be a First Alert AC10-500 smoke/CO alarm

[image]

[Manufacturer link](https://www.firstalert.com/more-safety-products/other-smart-home/hardwired-wi-fi-photoelectric-smoke-and-carbon-monoxide-alarm-with-10-year-battery/SAP_AC10-500.html)

P.S. First Alert may manufacture other alarms with a similar shape